# Как ускорить работу питон скрипта

Tags: numpy, python-3.6, pypy

Есть питон калькулятор для Holdem poker (не мой) вот ссылка [Holdem calc](https://github.com/ktseng/holdem_calc/blob/master/README.md). В случае если взможных комбинаций в раскладе много то очень долго считает. Например когда карты игроков известны а борд нет. 
Операционка Windows 10 , пробовал с помощью pypy3 запускать но он ещё дольше считает.

Вопрос как ускорить этот процесс. Я сам не программист, но совсем немного понимаю. Читал, что nympy быстрый но как с ним реализовать не пойму.

Заранее благодарен.

Вот пару примеров:

1)Результат Python 3.6 количество всевозможных ситуаций 658008 то-есть борд из 5 карт из 40 неизвестных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)Результат Python 3.6 количество всевозможных ситуаций 990 то-есть  2 карты из 45 неизвестных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3)Результат pypy3  количество всевозможных ситуаций 990 то-есть  2 карты из 45 неизвестных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так в чем вопрос?  Разбираться в программе и ее переписать? Так кому это надо. Подкинуть вам ссылку про numpy? Ну вот самое лучшее описание https://numpy.org/doc/. Считает долго - надо ставить более мощный процессор и больше памяти. В чем еще вам нужна помощь и какая?

Comment: https://github.com/ktseng/holdem_calc/blob/master/parallel_holdem_calc.py там же лежить распаралеленная версия